# How to change filename in a file input with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, angular-directive

Is there any way to change choosen file name? 
 For example, I choose a file name img1. On choosing the file it have to change to dynamicname. Is there any way to change name?

```
<input type="file" fd-input/>
```

[image]

Comment: Provide your code, instead of a screenshot, please.

Comment: Hi Mistalis , Its normal <input type="file">, i need to change selected image name to dynamic name.

Comment: Are you asking if you can rename a file on the user's computer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to change a filename inside a directive:

```
app.directive('file', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      file: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      el.bind('change', function(event) {
        var files = event.target.files;
        var file = files[0];
        scope.file = 'New file name';
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Use it as following:

```
<input type="file" file="param.file" />
```

### [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/3yexd6th/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to FormData you can use append method to change file name.

Refer this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) for more information.

```
var files = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
        var data = new FormData();
        var ext = files[0].name.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
        var fileName = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 19) + "." + ext;
        // Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection
        if (files.length > 0) {
            //data.append("UploadedImage", files[0]); //if you want to pass default name
            data.append("UploadedImage", files[0],fileName);
        }
```

HTML code -

```
<input id="fileUpload" type="file" ng-file-accept="'.jpg , .jpeg ,.bmp , .gif ,.png'" accept="image/*" />
```